# InstallScript: How to copy files optionally?

Tags: installshield

I have a question about InstallShield how to copy files optionally.
I created an InstallShield msi project. In this project, there are 2 files: "ISDataManager.dll" and "Broker.dll". 
All of them will be installed into "C:\Windows".

If anyone of the two files exists in the same location, the new files in the msi package will NOT be copied (just ignore it), how can I do that?

Thank you very much. (I use InstallShield 2011)

Answer (score 0):

In your Components viewer, check "ISDataManager.dll" and "Broker.dll files' properties, then select Always Overwrite checkbox.